# TimeoutException selenium chromedriver in Java when loading SSL cert website

Tags: java, selenium, ssl-certificate, selenium-chromedriver

I am receiving the following code error, whenever I run any test on my machine:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeOutException: timeout
(Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.78)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-87-generic x86_64)(WARNING:The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.02 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'oem-X555LJ', ip='127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-87-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities[{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e2e7cab51de5ba8), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.0teumv}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.78, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowsRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: ...
```

Things to note down:

I am accessing an URL with a SSL certificate, thus, putting the credentials in the form:

```
https://id:password@website
```

Whenever I try to access another website it works just fine.

Here is the way I am generating my chrome instance....:

```
package SeLib;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Reporter;

public class NewChrome {

    public static WebDriver Generate(Boolean maximized, DesiredCapabilities capabilities){

        WebDriver driver;

        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        Reporter.log("The browser is opened now");
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if(maximized){
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Reporter.log("The browser is maximized");
        }
        return driver;      
    }

    public static WebDriver Generate(Boolean maximized) throws InterruptedException{

        WebDriver driver;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        //options.addArguments("--start-maximized"); // gives problems with data provider

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
        prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs); 
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);      
        Reporter.log("The browser is opened now");
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        if(maximized){
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Reporter.log("The browser is maximized");
        }

        return driver;      
    }
}
```

I tried:

using a try/catch and refreshing the driver whenever the exception is caught -> same result, error persists.

removing implicit timeouts -> error persists.

updating chromedriver/chrome/selenium server -> error persists.

I am not sure if this is an error on the website I am working with, or whether my code has some mistake or something just broke down..

The thing is, I never changed my code but it suddenly stopped working by this error appearing, so IDK where lies the root of the problem..

Thank you, appreciate any help.

Jackson.